# Come back to the question below: tunnel and VPN

Tags: discussion

> Is tunnel a shortcut connection in internet? I read that tunnel is like protective
>   cover for data. How this protective cover is created. What is this protective mean? 
>   Is it like Encryption?

I think [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16650/tunnel-in-vpn-connection) is a good question. I don't know why it was marked "too broad...".

Could someone help me understand why it was closed?

Comment: softball question. Softball answer: [Network Tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol)

Answer (score 2):

> Is tunnel a shortcut connection in internet? I read that tunnel is like protective cover for data. How this protective cover is created. What is this protective mean? Is it like Encryption?

There are two fundamental problems with the question.

1. The OP quotes from an unknown source, and we have no idea what the original writer was talking about
2. The part about "How this protective cover is created" is too broad.  Furthermore without some reference for the kind of tunnel the OP is talking about, the whole thing is open-season for pot-shot answers which speculate about the OP's actual intent.

Is he asking about:

- IPSec Tunnels?
- SSL VPN tunnels?
- PPTP Tunnels?
- SSH Tunnels?
- OpenVPN Tunnels?

A person might respond that it doesn't matter because you can just write a generic answer about some encrypted tunnel.  However, that's beside the point; we [look for](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

*practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.*

Answer (score 0):

If he had asked "How do tunneling mechanism work?", would you have considered that too broad?  I think the OP just needed a bit of help with encapsulation and how that created a "tunnel" through the Internet.

If answers had gone the route of IPsec/SSL/SSH/etc, then I would argue the answers went off topic.  But I think the original question was (albeit oddly phrased) good enough that it deserved an answer.

Comment: Still too broad as we have no idea which of the dozens of tunneling methods to describe. STUN, DLsw, MPLS, q-in-q, ???

Comment: All of them in some form or another are a type of header inside another header.  I think that is all the OP was curious about.  And in that sense, the question wasn't very broad at all, it just didn't call for that much depth.  Either way, this is sort of in the past at this point.

Comment: Header+Payload is all networking is - in totality. Saying that's all a tunnel is, is a gross over simplification.

Comment: @rickybeam Yes, *you and I* know this. But this forum shouldn't be about showing off how much we know, but rather providing the most appropriate answer to the questioner.  He wasn't looking for depth, he was looking to understand a basic concept that was holding him up.  Sometimes the simplest answer is the best.  The art in answering questions is not in providing information, but in seeing what the questioner is held stuck on.